# Is there any way to annotate type of an list contents with sphinx in python?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Is there any way to annotate type of list's elements in sphinx like

```
def list_returning_function():
    """Returns an array of strings.

    :return: an array of strings
    :rtype: :class:`[str]`
    """
    return ['a', 'b', 'c']
```